# Python multiprocessing infinite loops

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to process simultaneously a function three times which contains an infinite loop.

My code:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(numbers):
    while True:
        print numbers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = ["1","2","3"]
    for i in nums:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker(i))
        p.start()
```

The problem is that keep looping only to "1"

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: Are you aware that `target=worker(i)` ___calls___ the function that contains an infinite loop? Your code never reaches `p.start()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per rawing's comment, instead of passing the function object to the `target` keyword argument, you are directly calling it and are passing its return value, which never returns since it's an infinite loop.

Try this:

```
import multiprocessing

_MAX_ITERATIONS = 10

def worker(numbers):
    iteration = 0
    while True:
        if iteration >= _MAX_ITERATIONS:
            break

        print(numbers)
        iteration += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = ["1","2","3"]
    for i in nums:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
```

I only added a `_MAX_ITERATIONS` guard for the sake of not having to kill the processes otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have not gone through the exact issue. But i had issue where I was using
 `multiprocessing.pool`, while doing `pool = Pool()`, I was not passing arguments to `Pool` like `Pool(4)`. So by default it was taking value equivalent to number of core ; and I was having same above issue.
After I used `pool = Pool(4)`, it was working fine.
Ps: number 4 can be replaced with other values.